# Custom validator on object in express-validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, express-validator

**Issue**

Custom validator not giving any response. I want to validate this below object in **express-validator**. The privilege key must be valid and exist in my array. If privilege object does not exist then the validation not working because it's optional but the value must be valid if the object exists

```
{

"email" : "john@gmail.com",
"privileges" : {
    "topic" : true
  }

}
```

**user.js**

```
 const User = require('../../models/User');
 const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

 let privilegesArray = ['topic'];

 router.post(
 '/',
 [

   check("privileges")
  .custom(async (value, { req }) => {
   Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key){
   if(!privilegesArray.includes(key)){
      return false;
      }
   if(value[key] === 'true' || value[key] === 'false' || value[key] === ''){
      return false;
      }
   })
  }).withMessage("Invalid privileges").optional({checkFalsy: true})

],
 async (req, res) => {
 const errors = validationResult(req);
 if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
 }

}
);
```

I am a beginner in node-js and not using any custom validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so there are few problems with your script:

1. Within the custom handler, you are iterating using `forEach`:

   ```
   Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key){
       if(!privilegesArray.includes(key)){
          return false;
   ```

   the problem is, however, that you are returning `false` from within the internal forEach handler, not the `custom` handler itself.
2. You shouldn't be returning by the way, according to [documentation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html). You should throw an error instead.
3. You didn't provide handler if everything goes well, eg. `return res.status(200).json({ errors: "[]" });` in case everything goes fine in route handler.
4. **Most important** I guess, you didn't register any `bodyParser`. I'm pretty sure express won't be able to understand application/json in the POST body: `app.use(bodyParser.json());`
5. After middleware parses input jsons, you shouldn't be comparing `value[key] === 'true'`, as it's going to be boolean `true`.

Below is complete code which seems to meet your requirements, tested using fiddler:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
let privilegesArray = ["topic"];
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post(
  "/",
  [
    check("privileges")
      .custom(async (value, { req }) => {
        var keys = Object.keys(value);
        for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
          var key = keys[k];
          if (!privilegesArray.includes(key)) continue;
          if (
            value[key] !== true &&
            value[key] !== false &&
            value[key] !== ""
          ) {
            throw new Error("Topic is invalid.");
          }
        }
        return true;
      })
      .withMessage("Invalid privileges")
      .optional({ checkFalsy: true }),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = await validationResult(req);
    console.log(errors);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ errors: "[]" });
  }
);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I also wanted to check the key is exist in my privilegesArray. if not then I will throw the error like this ** if (!privilegesArray.includes(key)) throw new Error("Invalid topic key")**; is it OK?

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. That's the thing I wanted (Y)

Comment: Sure then instead of `continue` you throw an error.